# Code for Bottom Footer

Tags: css, html, footer

I have a slight problem with making the footer work, as the div's aren't going where I want them to go.

Imagine that the image  was at the bottom of the page, at the footer, how would you get the links there? It is going to be spread across the whole of the bottom bit of the page, and I was wondering if you guys could help me out please, as this website that I am making has to look superb.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#nav {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
width: 600px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;

}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
#nav li a {
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
color:black;
}
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
color:#C7C7C7;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
color:#009ACD;
text-decoration:none;
}

h1 {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
color:white;
width:900px;
left:50%;
right:50%;
margin-top: 0;
font-size:36px;
}

#header {
margin-top: 0;
width:100%;
height:150px;
background-color:#09F;
}

font {
font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYMCc/1/)**

Comment: please share your html and css that would help us to find the issue

Comment: can you give us source code of that? I have better solution of this. but I need source code.

Comment: I have just edited it

Comment: Html? Make a fiddle, please.

Comment: Could you make a link to the fiddle please

Comment: Like the link to where i can make a fiddle please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cYMCc/1/

Comment: What is your main problem?

Comment: How can i get the links at the bottom of the pages like the image in the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#footer .nav li:nth-child(even) {
    top: 70px; /* eg. */
}
```

or

```
#footer .nav li:nth-child(2n+0) {
    top: 70px; /* eg. */
}
```

Don't forget to put

```
#footer .nav li {
    position: relative;
}
```

#### Update

Added some code to justify li elements. See jsfiddle link. 
And then you can style navigation as you like. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/Nxdjz/)

Full screen view [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/Nxdjz/embedded/result/)

Comment: Sorry, i already have a menu bar at the top, its just at the footer. Is there any chance that you could link me to the jsfiddle for an update of this website please :) Thank you for your  answer

Comment: How would you make it in the circles?

Comment: For some reason i can't put the links inside the background

Comment: Please could you help me with that, like put the links inside the background at the bottom of the page